# не идёт ожидание

Tags: javascript, время

Вместо того, чтобы каждый раз ждать 1 секунду, он дожидается конца цикла, ждёт одну секунду и обновляет объект. Подскажите, где ошибка, и как я могу её решить.
Вот код:

```
function startTimer() {
    var seconds2 = document.getElementById('second').innerHTML
    var minutes2 = document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML
    var hours2 = document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML
    alert('hi')
    while(seconds2 != "00") {
        if (seconds2 > 2 || seconds2 != "00") {
            seconds2 = seconds2 - 1
            if(seconds2.toString().length < 2) {
                seconds2 = "0" + seconds2
            }
            setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = seconds2}, 1000)
            // alert(seconds2)
        }   
        // } else if (seconds2 == 1) {
        //     if (minutes2 != "00" || minutes2 != 0) {
        //         minutes2 -= 1
        //         seconds2 = 59
        //     }
        //     // } else if(hours2 != "00" || minutes2 != 0)
        // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему дубликат? Мне было интересно, как можно исправить мою проблему. Если же вы и закрыли мой вопрос, то оставьте ссылку на другой, а то вы оставляете меня без ответа, и мне опять придётся искать информацию.

Comment: У меня проблема не в этом!

Comment: Смотрел ли ты вопрос дубликат?

Comment: Добавил еще один дубликат

Comment: да. Я уже решил проблему с помощью рекурсивного setTimeout(). Кстати, вы не знаете, как можно останлвить его?

Comment: Просто не запускать его, если выполняется какое-то условие.

Comment: Спасибки) Всё получилось.